# Unlock mutex on exception

Tags: c++, exception, mutex

```
mutex.lock();
try
{
    foo(); // can throw exception
}
catch (...)
{
    mutex.unlock();
    throw;
}
mutex.unlock();
```

To guaranty the unlock i must call `mutex.unlock()` in catch block and in normal case. Is there any option to avoid duplication?

Thank You

Comment: Yes, simply use an [std::lock_guard](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock_guard).

Comment: Search for "RAII", which is applicable beyond this case.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What you are looking for is a mutex wrapper like [`std::lock_guard`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock_guard):

```
#include <mutex>
std::mutex _mutex;

void call_foo()
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(_mutex);

    try
    {
        foo(); // can throw exception
    }
    catch (...)
    {
         // the mutex is unlocked here...

         throw;
    }

    // ... and here
}
```

When `lock` goes out of scope, its destructor unlocks the underlying mutex `_mutex`.

**See also** [`std::unique_lock`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/unique_lock), this class provides some more features and might add some more overhead. In this case a`std::lock_guard` is sufficient.